# Angularjs way, conditionally to generate new form and append it to the page or state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am  new to angularjs,
and wonder What is the angularjs way to complete such a task as conditionally generating or showing the form ? 
Lets say

```
$scope.counter = function(){
   if ($scope.years < 5){

    // what is here? append or should  return true and use ng-if directive in html?

    }}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.years = 10;
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<label>age :</label>
  <input type="number" ng-model="years">
  <div ng-if="years<5"> show if years < 5 </div>
  <div ng-if="years>5"> show if years > 5 </div>
</div>
```

just like that

Comment: Thank you, the only thing, would you suggest to take the user to another state view containing the form, or the way with directives  preferred ?

Comment: I don't know all your application, but it a good idea to dynamically generate form in the same state, if your form is big, you can also use a wizard form

Comment: like http://embed.plnkr.co/M03tYgtfqNH09U4x5pHC/preview (or other "wizard form angularjs" on google)

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should do it from `HTML` file via by `ng-if\ng-show\ng-hide` directives.

Like below (`years` should be part of controller\component):

```
<div ng-if="years<5"> html code </div>
```